# like operator with right side match % in arraylist in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

This is an array and yii query builder

```
$arr = ['delhi','mumbai'];
$query->orWhere(['LIKE','city',$arr."%",false]);
```

i want to generate where condition like this

```
where city like 'delhi%' or city like 'mumbai%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference source code: `\yii\db\QueryBuilder::buildLikeCondition()`

```
$cities = ['city1', 'city2', 'city3'];
$query = new \yii\db\Query();

$query->where(['or like', 'city', array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item.'%';
}, $cities), false]); 

print_r($query->createCommand()->rawSql);

// output: SELECT * WHERE `city` LIKE 'city1%' OR `city` LIKE 'city2%' OR `city` LIKE 'city3%'
```

Comment: you need to replace `$array` with `$cities` just corrected it

Answer (score -1):

Just use [SIMILAR TO in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-matching.html) or [REGEXP_LIKE in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) (depending of your database engine) instead of LIKE

For example your query should look like:

```
$query->andWhere(['SIMILAR TO', 'city','('.implode('|', $arr).')%',false]);
```